# Alter table decimal field?

Tags: mysql, sql

I tried to alter table with decimal type:

```
porog   decimal(6,0)
```

When I change range on the (6, 4) and save it, I get again (6,0). Why?

Now I have field `decimal(15,14)`

When I insert value:

`3,41557740625523`

I get: `3.00000000000000`

Comment: So how do you make this change?

Comment: And just a side note: Isn't `decimal(6,0)` basically an integer?

Comment: So I tried to store number with 14 numbers after coma, and integer part is 0-000. What decimal format I should use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I built up a simple scheme to test the things you mentioned, but I cannot reproduce your problems concerning the loss of after-comma digits. Can it be that any sql client or query does some rounding? Anyway, have a look at the scheme, the inserts and the output. Maybe it helps and answers at least your question about "What decimal format I should use?":

```sql
create table test (
  yourfield decimal(15,14),
  onlyaftercomma decimal(18,18)
);
insert into test (yourfield,onlyaftercomma) values
  (3.41557740625523, 0.00041557740625523);
```

Then...

```sql
select * from test
```

yields...

```sql
yourfield        | onlyaftercomma
3.41557740625523 | 0.00041557740625523
```